# Integrating KalViewController with EKEventStore

Tags: ios, iphone

I am thinking about using EKEventStore with Kal calendar.

I have the calendar working with the SQLiteDataSource in Kal's example, but can't figure out how to integrate the dataSource with EKEventStore.

As a starting point some code:

```
kal.delegate = self;
dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc] init];
kal.dataSource = dataSource;`
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was right in front of me and I missed it. One of Kal's examples NativeCal employs EKEventKit :)